# Not able to write splitted text in json file in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am testing an application where the alert text says like
**Customer added successfully with customer id :13**
Now i want to grab 13 and save it in json file.
Somehow its not getting written in json file.
Please help
Below is my code

```
export function stripcustomerid() {
cy.on('window:alert', (txt) => {
    cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/account_details.json').then((data) => {
        var customerno = txt.split(':')
        const cno = customerno[1]
        data.customerid = cno
        cy.writeFile(
            'cypress/fixtures/account_details.json',
            JSON.stringify(data)
        )
    })
})
```

}

Comment: What do you get when you `cy.log(cno)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `txt` variable has the string `Customer added successfully with customer id :13` and also your `account_details.json` file has an existing customer id data like `customerid: 55`, because you are changing this value. Then your code looks correct.

You can replace these three lines:

```js
var customerno = txt.split(':')
const cno = customerno[1]
data.customerid = cno
```

with

```js
data.customerid = txt.split(':')[1]
```

Comment: Its still not working

Comment: Can you log txt and check whther you are getting the value ?

Comment: There is a whitespace in alert text after id.How to remove that
Customer added successfully with customer id :6

Comment: You can add trim`txt.trim().split(':')[1]`. This will remove all the white space from beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Is there any other way.Can we use cy.stub()

Comment: can you add the screenshot of the alert you ger and also the html code.